# How to track time using Open talk iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using open talk iOS SDK in one of my project. I wanted to track the call time. What is the best approach should I use to track time.
Following are two approaches I am thinking to implement
1) Create timer to keep track 
2) Time difference between start and end time of call

Please let me know is there any other better option available

Comment: Time difference between start and end time of call is better one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSTimer option as well to keep track of time. other wise check whether any api available  into OpenTalk which keep track of time. As suggested time difference between start and end time is also efficient

Answer (score 0):

As a time is initialized with a predefined time interval and is not giving you the interval it's been running I would suggest capturing start and end time using `[NSDate date]` and calculating the time difference using `timeIntervalSinceDate:` which will give you the seconds between the two dates.

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *endDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval diff = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate: startDate];
```